# Why am I not able to use inline-block on div tags?

Tags: xhtml, css

I have the following sample code and noticed that if I attempt to use the declaration `display:inline-block` on the div element `content`, it doesn't place its descendants or children side by side.

The only way for me to have the `p` element appear adjacent to one another is to apply the style to the `p` selector. Does this mean I cannot use `display: inline-block` on descendants, children and siblings?

**Code**

```
<DOCTYPE public HTML "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http=equiv="content-language" content="en-us" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <meta name="copyright" content="&copy; 2012" />
        <title>Inline-block</title>

        <base href="" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="" />

        <style type="text/css" media="all">

        p {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100px;
        }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <p>paragraph 1</p>
            <p>paragraph 2</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inline-block should apply to siblings, but not children.  Try something like this:

```
#content p {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Why use the property `content` if it is only applied to `p`?

Comment: I also take it you mean that `p` is the child if `content` and anything under `p` would be its siblings.

Comment: If you apply the rule to the selector p, then that means the rule will apply to any <p> elements in your document.  Right now you've only got 2, but <p> is a common element so you're likely to have more later and that could cause problems down the line.

Comment: In your posted code, <p> is the child of <div id="content">.  Since there are two <p> elements, the parent element of both <p>'s is <div id="content">.  Because they share they same parent, the <p> elements are siblings.  Any more elements inside of one of the <p> elements would be children of <p>.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the property on the element you want displayed that way. The `display` property is not inherited by children. Also it should be noted they IE7 only accepts `inline-block` on elements that are inline by default.